# How to prove that boundaries, interiors and closures of invariant sets are also invariant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I saw the fact quoted in the title in a paper ([1], page 12) and a book ([2], page 38). It is, however, mentioned only in passing and no proofs are given. Therefore, I assumed it must be a fairly general and obvious fact with a short proof -- but I couldn't figure it out myself.

It'd be great to see such a proof if I'm indeed right. If I'm wrong (the claim is wrong, or it is only true under certain conditions, or it is non-obvious and has a very long proof), a pointer in the right direction will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance for the help!

[1] Ciesielski, Krzysztof. "Boundary properties for two dimensional semiflows." (1997).

[2] Chiang, Hsiao-Dong. Direct Methods for Stability Analysis of Electric Power Systems: Theoretical Foundation, BCU Methodologies, and Applications. Wiley, 2011.

**NOTE**: An invariant set in this context is most probably both forward and backward invariant; i.e. a set $S$ is invariant iff $x \in S \implies \forall t \in \mathbb{R} \; \phi(t, x) \in S$; where $\phi$ is the flow of the dynamical system. The claim is obviously wrong for forward invariance alone, so I'm assuming that is not what was meant.

Also, note that the vector field inducing the flow has to be continuous. It is easy to construct counter-examples otherwise. (*added Monday 11/06*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a proof of the stated fact in Gerald Teschl's book [1]. See Lemma's 8.4 and 6.4. The author proves the stated fact for the closure, and the rest follows easily using the fact that the difference of two invariant sets are invariant.

[1] Teschl, Gerald. [Ordinary differential equations and dynamical systems](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/index.html). Vol. 140. AMS Bookstore, 2012.